# Do my opponents get a penalty to see me if I sneak up from behind?

Tags: dragon-age-rpg

My friends and I started a Dragon Age Roleplay and in the situation "A rogue approaches a creature from behind," we must test the creature's sight against the rogue's dexterity.
An argument arose that the creature doesn't receive a penalty for facing the other direction.
The GM said that it's not written in the rules, while I think that it's only natural for a penalty in the opposing check.

Can someone help me with that argument? *Does* the creature get a penalty, or not?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Judging by the [QuickStart rules](http://greenronin.com/support/files/21) available on Green Ronin's site, you are both correct. This example is explicitly mentioned as an Opposed Test:

> The counterparts in an opposed test sometimes use different abilities. For example, a character attempting to sneak past a guard rolls his Dexterity (Stealth) against the guard’s Perception (Hearing).
>
> If one character has a particular advantage over his opponent that’s not already reflected by his ability or focus, those circumstances may give him a bonus or penalty to his roll. Such modifiers are usually no worse than –3 or better than +3.

So sneaking on a guard is a simple opposed roll, and there's no mention of "sneaking from behind" as a specific modifier. The question then becomes, based on the second paragraph, what constitutes "a particular advantage not already reflected by his ability".

Since sneaking from behind is the *standard* way of sneaking, after all, it can be assumed that sneak skill takes this into account, and this doesn't constitute a "particular advantage" - it's already reflected in the ability.

What seems to be bothering you is the disconnect between what the rules specify and what feels *right*, or *natural*. The basis for this discrepancy is that actions in most role-playing games aren't granular. An attack, for instance, isn't just a swing of a sword, but several seconds of maneuvering to get to that one strike.  Similarly, a person standing around is considered, in most situations, to be aware - looking around occasionally, maybe turning. This is why sneaking from behind isn't automatically a special circumstance - the guard's Perception skill automatically includes checking around and turning. It's a slightly more abstract, compound action, not just "does he hear me".

The solution, if you feel like you want that bonus, is to *create* that "particular advantage". If you create a distraction, for instance, that keeps the guard's attention fixed in the other direction, you should be able to get a bonus from it.

Comment: As lisardggY explains, the rules for sneaking assume no facing, and everybody effectively has 360 degree vision all the time (being aware, looking around).

Answer (score 2):

The core rulebook first abstractly states that circumstances should be illustrated with bonuses or penalties during a opposed test.

**Core Rulebook** at chapter 9, page **213** regarding **Opposed Tests** :

> Generally speaking,
> you should grant bonuses or impose penalties of 1-3 to reflect
> the circumstances of the test

> Factors you may consider for bonuses and/or penalties to
> ability tests include equipment available, weather conditions,
> time constraints, distractions, assistance from others, lighting
> conditions, and good roleplaying where appropriate

Those rules, as you can read a little further in the book would also apply on attack rolls, moreover those *special circumstances* are a bit described.

From the **Core Rulebook** at chapter 9, **page 216** regarding **Attack Rolls
& Circumstance** :

> You **can also assign bonuses** and
> penalties to the attack roll to reflect the circumstances of the
> encounter, just as you do in opposed tests. In general these
> bonuses and penalties should range from 1 to 3. They can take
> into account anything that would affect the attacker’s ability
> to hit the target, such as lighting, terrain, **tactics**, and concealment.

*Sneak attack* ability already reflects the fact that your avatar deals extra *sneak* damages on a target he is not already engaged with. If a bonus would be applied it should respond to a particular/unuasual situation, as brought by the player for example.

In the end bonus is always up to the GM, but rules as written should incitate your GM to give a +1 to +3 bonus to reward good or successful tactical approach.

On that same page, there are some examples on the **Attack roll modifiers** table with bonuses and maluses that apply and in which situations :

> +3 : Defender is unaware of the attack.

Given a target unaware of the player, facing the other way. From the above rules, I would allow a player to :

- Sneak on the unaware target maybe with a -1 to -3 penalty (depending on game factors)
- Do a *sneak attack* with a +3 bonus upon successful *Dexterity (Sneak)* test against target's *Perception (Hearing)*
- Apply *sneak attack* damages upon successful attack roll